# Use of aux. "be" with "got" for passive?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

> Someone got full marks in the exam.

Is it possible to change its voice to passive using **got** as follows?

> Full marks were got by someone.

Why or why not?

Comment: It's grammatically possible, yes, but rather unlikely.

Comment: I agree that *be* sounds odd. A bit better if you use  *get* as the auxiliary. *Don't get gotten!* *Full marks got gotten by Thomas.* I would like to think why that is so but it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 6):

There's a difference between "past tense" and "past participle". When you're forming the passive voice, you use the past participle.

In British English, the past tense and past participle are the same for "to get".

> Full marks were **got** by someone.

However, in American English, the past participle is "gotten".

> Full marks were **gotten** by someone.

Though this is proper, it still sounds a little awkward. If you insist on using the passive voice, you might use a synonym.

> Full marks were *achieved* by someone.

or...

> Full marks were *acquired* by someone.

Comment: You learn something new... I never knew that "got" was an acceptable past participle, but I see that you're correct. I'll include it.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting better alternatives.

Comment: Being a Brit we use got as past part. This construction sounds strange however. A better verb would clearly be achieved. I was wondering if a rule means the combination of was/were plus got is not possible.

Comment: @Gralefrit It does sound strange, but it is technically correct. The strangeness is what prompted me to suggest alternatives.